# Browserify - create bundle with external module

Tags: javascript, npm, browserify

I'm really new to browserify world.
I want to use this module [peer-file](https://www.npmjs.org/package/peer-file), in order to allow the file transfer between two browsers. Reading the Usage section into readme, I note I have to include the script bundle.js in my web page. To build the bundle I need to type `browserify -r ./index.js > build.js`, where `-r` option means external require, so I can use in my main script the keyword `require()`, like this:

```
var send = require('peer-file/send')
var receive = require('peer-file/receive')
```

However, when I load the web page, I receive this error into the console.
`Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'peer-file/send'`

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the index file - https://github.com/michaelrhodes/peer-file/blob/master/index.js

It adds `send` and `receive` to the exports. So you first get a handle to that, then you can access the exports with dot notation.

```
var send = require('peer-file').send;
var receive = require('peer-file').receive;
```

Or just get it once:

```
var peerFile = require('peer-file');

// Later
peerFile.send..
peerFile.receive..
```

Comment: I did like you said, but I got "Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'peer-file'". Maybe have I create the bundle typing:
`browserify -r ./index.js:peer-file > build.js`?

Comment: I followed this: https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#external-requires. So the noun after the **:** means the name associated to the exported module. Am I right?

Comment: Does your project have a package.json (generated with `npm init`) and you have the module listed there in `dependencies` and it is installed into a `node_modules` folder?

Comment: Yes, but after that, I need to move the bundle.js file into the public folder - I'm working with express. Anyway, the answer is yes.

Comment: I recommend you use grunt or gulp to set up your build task. I also recommend you use webpack instead of browserify as it is much faster at compiling. Setting up a build task in grunt or gulp for this is simple - can't see exactly what you are doing wrong without seeing your project though

Comment: I do not know gulp and grunt, but I'd like to learn them. Anyway,  building the build.js file as __browserify -r ./index.js:peer-file > build.js__ I solved my issue, in fact I can access to send and receive like you wrote above. So, thank you so much!

Comment: @BrunoBruzzano np, sorry I didn't realise you had to specify the peer-file module in the command line, good to know!