# Using Browserify to create React Bundle

Tags: reactjs, browserify

It's the same question as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33815617/use-of-browserify-to-pack-react-components), but I don't understand the answer. So, my question is about the answer.

The answer is

> Your react.js file/module isn't exposing the variables React and
>   ReactDOM you instantiate. In node, you make these methods public by
>   modifying the module.exports object like so:
>
> `module.exports = {   React: React,   ReactDOM: ReactDOM }`

Finally, my question is: Where do "you make these methods public"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making these methods public by defining them on the `module.exports` property.  For instance, say you have a file reactExports.js with

```
var iWontGetThere = 'I am in this module only';
module.exports = { React: React, ReactDOM: ReactDOM }
```

now in another file, you can require these methods and use them, like so:

```
var React = require('reactExports').React;
var SweetComponent = React.createClass({
   render: function() {
     return (
        <div>React is cool and I can use it in here!</div>
     );
   }
});
module.exports = SweetComponent;
```

Now imagine you want to render SweetComponent in another component.  If I hadn't written `module.exports = SweetComponent`, requiring this module in another component would have no effect as all as you would be importing an empty object `{}`.
Let's say I tried to `console.log(React.iWontGetThere);`  What would happen?  I would get a reference error, as it was not exported with the contents of reactExports.js-it only exists in that module, but it is not exposed.

This is a contrived example, but the interesting story here is the ability to bring in encapsulated modules.  I suggest reading more about node modules [here](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_modules)
and checking out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137397/module-exports-vs-exports-in-node-js) as well.
and making some examples to get the hang of it.

tl;dr: defining variables and not having a `module.exports = some_value` statement then requiring that same file will default to an empty object.